# Python3 - Bounding Box - Calculate the line position on the page

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, pdfminer

I have a XML file that contains some bounding box information from a PDF file:

```xml
<page bbox="0.000,0.000,612.000,792.000" rotate="0">
    <textbox bbox="21.600,733.350,65.644,751.641">
        <textline bbox="21.600,733.350,65.644,751.641">
            <text bbox="21.600,733.350,30.258,751.641">L</text>
            <text bbox="30.258,733.350,37.486,751.641">i</text>
            <text bbox="37.486,733.350,44.714,751.641">n</text>
            <text bbox="44.714,733.350,48.315,751.641">e</text>
            <text bbox="48.315,733.350,55.543,751.641">#</text>
            <text bbox="55.543,733.350,62.043,751.641">1</text>
        </textline>
    </textbox>

    <textbox bbox="21.600,714.720,140.775,729.494">
        <textline bbox="21.600,714.720,140.775,729.494">
            <text bbox="27.438,714.720,29.769,729.494"ncolour="1"size="14.774">L</text>
            <text bbox="21.600,714.720,27.438,729.494"ncolour="1"size="14.774">i</text>
            <text bbox="29.769,714.720,35.019,729.494"ncolour="1"size="14.774">n</text>
            <text bbox="35.019,714.720,40.857,729.494"ncolour="1"size="14.774">e</text>
            <text bbox="40.857,714.720,43.188,729.494"ncolour="1"size="14.774">#</text>
            <text bbox="43.188,714.720,49.026,729.494"ncolour="1"size="14.774">2</text>
        </textline>
    </textbox>

    <textbox bbox="223.560,717.899,457.560,754.481">
        <textline bbox="223.560,717.899,457.560,754.481">
        <text font="EAAAAA+ArialUnicodeMS" bbox="223.560,717.899,242.332,754.481" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0.098" size="36.582">L</text>
        <text font="EAAAAA+ArialUnicodeMS" bbox="242.332,717.899,248.104,754.481" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0.098" size="36.582">i</text>
        <text font="EAAAAA+ArialUnicodeMS" bbox="248.104,717.899,261.104,754.481" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0.098" size="36.582">n</text>
        <text font="EAAAAA+ArialUnicodeMS" bbox="261.104,717.899,275.560,754.481" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0.098" size="36.582">e</text>
        <text font="EAAAAA+ArialUnicodeMS" bbox="275.560,717.899,281.332,754.481" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0.098" size="36.582">#</text>
        <text font="EAAAAA+ArialUnicodeMS" bbox="281.332,717.899,295.788,754.481" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0.098" size="36.582">1</text>
        </textline>
    </textbox>
</page>
```

Above simply spell out

```
Line #1
Line #2
Line #1
```

I am trying to parse a PDF file to text and keep the formatting. 
For this, I guess I need to use the `bbox` information to somehow calculate the position on the page (what line # the `textline` tag is located on).

I have the width and height of the page. In this case it is `612.000,792.000`

Can anyone guide me in the direction on how to parse this. Until now, I have only been able to parse each line and append each character to spell each word - but then each `<textbox>` is being treated as a separate line:

```py
tree = ET.parse(path_to_xml_file)
root = tree.getroot()
lines = {}
textboxes = root.findall('./page/textbox')
for textbox in textboxes:
    for line in words:
        for char in line.text:
            [...]
```

How can I parse the `bbox` information and calculate the line number that the `<textline>` tag is located on?

Comment: What is the formula for calculating the line number?

Comment: That’s what I am searching for input on. Right now I don’t exactly know where to start. I am not sure it’s possible to calculate the line number from bbox information to begin with. Hopefully someone has done it before?

Comment: What I understand the bbox position could be everywhere on the page. It doesn't depend on line numbering.

Comment: Exactly - however I was wondering if it’s possible to calculate what “line number” the text/bbox is on. For example, if the page height is 612 pixels and we have the coordinates for each textline found, isn’t it possible to determine that each line for example is 20 pixels in height and then determine where the textline is?

Comment: Could textbox span over multiple lines?

Comment: Yes and no, because it will be wrapped in it’s own `<textbox>` tag, where the bounding box coordinates would represent that it is further down the page (thus being on a new line)

Comment: @AndrejKesely I was thinking - maybe it was possible to start off by modifying the XML and sort the `<textline>` tag by the `bbox[1]` value? And then iterate over each textline tag - and if the `bbox[1]` value is the same (+/- a few pixels), add a new attr to the tag called `line=`? Then do a loop over the XML and group the tags where `line=` is the same?

Comment: I made simple program to extract textboxes and calculate width, height https://pastebin.com/gtZWYXQZ Every textbox has different height, so for every textbox is different line numbering?